# How to proxy_pass only remaining URL after a match

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Only need to proxy pass remaining url when match to location

```
location /blog { proxy_pass http://example.com }
```

i.e if somebody requests `/blog/page1/temp.html` they are getting proxy passed to `example.com/blog/page1/temp.html`

I want to change it to `example.com/page1/temp.html`

Answer (score 2):

> I want to change example.com/blog/page1/temp.html to example.com/page1/temp.html

Specify uri into proxy pass directive (`/` after hostname in this case):

```
location /blog/ {
    proxy_pass http://example.com/;
}
```

Or use rewrite like this:

```
location /blog {
    rewrite /blog/([^/]+) $1;
    proxy_pass http://example.com
}
```